# C boolean creation and insert value without calling structure member - directly value insert

Tags: c

in c language we know there is `(_Bool)` type which is 1 byte. also it's possible to create own boolean type using this structure

```
typedef struct { char value : 1; } boolean_t;
```

and call it like this

```
boolean_t var1;
var1.value = 0;
```

but i want to not use (`.value`) and just do this

```
var 1 = 0;
```

like `(_Bool)` type (no structure inside variable call for insert the value) i want something like this

```
boolean_t var1;
var1 = 0;
```

how can i do this?

Comment: C++ is not C. Please don't spam tags

Comment: There is no requirement that `_Bool` be one byte.  It needs to be able to store two distinct values, which means `sizeof(_Bool)` may be `1`, but there is nothing preventing it from exceeding `1`.  There is also no means to force `some_struct = 1` to have the effect of setting `some_struct.some_particular_member = 1`.   `_Bool` is an integral type, which is why it has a value, rather than one or more members that can be set.

Comment: Why not use `typedef char mybool` ?

Comment: Boolean in C is an integer, that is just zero for false and non zero for true.

Comment: This seems like a XY problem. Unless you are using ancient C89 compiler, defining your own bool type is always an antipattern. What are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

In C, booleans can be represented by variable that can have either value 0 (false) or not 0 (true). You could use an unsigned char like that:

```
typedef unsigned char boolean_t;
boolean_t myBool = 0; // or myBool = 1
```

Comment: this is wrong ... because you can use other values (to 255) too for this and it's not what i want ... i want to be only one bit to use only (0 and 1)

Comment: @itmanwork One bit is not possible in C and I think in every other programming language as well: the minimum size of an element is a memory is at least 1 byte. Therefore, unless with compile-time checks, it is not possible to prevent other values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you want (By this I mean that you can't have a datatype which is just 1 bit long and can be used with assignment `=`). The one you showed - that will also take atleast 1 byte of memory. Also using signed you constrained yourself with the use of `0` and `-1` to hold `0` and `1` use unsigned. The smallest addressable unit being `byte` in [c](/questions/tagged/c) it is not possible to have a datatype that takes up space less than a byte. (Same hold for `_Bool` also).

Again here you could have simply used `uint8_t` to achieve the same thing. `uint8_t v = 1; //denotes true and so on`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be weird to use a struct for a boolean type. Many things could work for example with your `boolean_t`, ensure the internal value can only be 0 or 1 because of the bitfield, assign a boolean to true and false from two const values, maybe more.

But in C a struct cannot be assigned from an integral value, not can it be used as an integer expression. That means that at least two things would be impossible:

```
boolean b;
b = (1 < 2);             // error assigning to struct from incompatible type int
if (b) printf("true\n"); // error used type struct where int or pointer required
```

Because in C relational operators actually return int values